# is there a way of implementing the following method, such that is gets called in time?

Tags: c#, wcf

I now have the following code, which calls a WCF service, it get some data and then pass the data on to the browser.

The only problem is that client_GetProductCompleted() does not get called until Load() finishes, and by then, it is too late. The browser has already loaded the information.

So basically I am asking, if there is a way of implementing the methods, such that client_GetProductCompleted() gets called as soon as Load() gets called, then it can return the data back to the browser in time :)

It is probably silly, but I have tried to ask the program to sleep while waiting for Load() to finish, and it didnt work. So Im totally clueless now ...

```
public static Products _OurProducts = new Products();

public void Load()
{
    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
    client.getProductsCompleted += 
        new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.getProductsCompletedEventArgs>(
            client_GetProductCompleted);

    client.getProductsAsync();    
    return;
}

void client_GetProductCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.getProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.Product> products = e.Result;
        foreach (ServiceReference1.Product prod in products)
        {
            Product temp = new Product(prod);
            _OurProducts.Add(temp);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: methodA? methodB?  these do not appear to be in your example

Comment: Where is `methodA` and `methodB`? And when is `Load` called?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will change that, I meant Load() and client_GetProductCompleted() methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't completely clear, but I *suspect* you want `MethodA` to block until the handler finishes executing (presumably on another thread).

It's possible that the object you are querying offers a synchronous way of returning its results. This would definitely be the way to go if available.

If not, you can make the method block until it is signaled, such as with a [**`ManualResetEvent`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

E.g.:

```
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
client.getProductsCompleted += (s, e) => 
                               { 
                                   client_GetProductCompleted(s, e); 
                                   resetEvent.Set();
                               };    
client.getProductsAsync(); 
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. Yes, i realized that oberservableCollections can automatically fire events when it is updated, so I just need to listen to the event, and tell the browser to update the event when the data has been updated :)